# Fluent NHibernate: How to map two non-key columns

Tags: nhibernate

How would I be able to Map an object inside of another with two columns that arent keys?

```
public class Car
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int AccountId { get; set; }
}

public class UserAccount
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int UserId{ get; set; }
    public virtual int AccountId { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int Name { get; set; }
}
```

Lets say I wanted to get all Cars with a User.Name of "joe". How would I map / query these with fluent nhibernate?

```
    public Car()
    {
        Table("Car");
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("ID").GeneratedBy.Native();
        Map(x => x.AccountId);
        References(x => x.Account); // ?? needs to map accountid with the Account.Id...
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to map a reference, you need the type, not the key.

```
public class Car
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual UserAccount Account { get; set; }
}
```

Then you would map it like this

```
public Car()
{
    Table("Car");
    Id(x => x.Id).Column("ID").GeneratedBy.Native();
    References(x => x.Account, "AccountId");
}
```

Comment: so the References(x => x.Account, "AccountId"), is assuming that the AccountId will walys be the primary key?

Comment: No, AccountId is just the column name. By saying "reference" it will then use the mapping information for the `UserAccount` type to load / join to get the information

Comment: Do I need to do anything with the mapping in the UserAccount for the reference in the Car to work?

Comment: Nope, you just need to map the user account as another ClassMap, then nhibernate understands how to do it.

Comment: so what if you write References(x => x.Account, "AccountId") for Car, but you are trying to link the Car "AccountId" with the Account "Id" (two different names)

Comment: In your mapping for UserAccount, you map the `Id(x => x.Id).Column("ID")` so nhibernate knows that maps from AccountId <==> Id

Comment: but how does nhibernate know that accountId from one table is referencing Id from Account? sorry for the questions, just want to fully understand

Comment: That's just how references works. Same concept as foreign key. The intent is that this column holds the primary key value for the given type.

Comment: thanks a ton Darren, you helped me a bunch. So would you recommend always using References for that kind of situation? even if it could be many?

Comment: Use `References` for a many-to-one, or `HasOne` for a one-to-one, or Any for `many-to-any` I think.